# Help me to solve a basic (?) differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you help me to solve the following basic differential equation:
$$
\frac{ax}{(\pm b \pm cy \pm ex)} \frac{dy}{dx} = cst
$$

Comment: Why do you call that "basic" ?

Comment: Since I'm novice, I thought it was trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation can be written in a linear form, $$y'+p\frac yx=\frac qx+r.$$

The homogeneous part has the solution

$$y=x^{-p},$$ and by division

$$y'x^p+px^{p-1}y=qx^{p-1}+rx^p$$

yields, for $p\ne0$ and $p\ne-1$,

$$yx^p=\frac qp x^p+\frac r{p+1}x^{p+1}+c$$ or

$$y=\frac qp+\frac r{p+1}x+cx^{-p}.$$

---

For $p=0$, we immediately get

$$y=q\log x+rx+c,$$

and for $p=-1$,

$$y=-q+rx\log x+cx.$$

Comment: @Chris_toph: you integrate both sides.

Comment: I've difficulties to get how you integrate 
$$
y'x^p+px^{p-1}y=qx^{p-1}+rx^p
$$
to
$$
yx^p=\frac qp x^p+\frac r{p+1}x^{p+1}+c
$$
Dare I ask you to give more details..?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Chris_toph: what are you missing ?

Comment: I did not manage! can you show me the intermediate steps on how to integrate..?
$$
x^p\,dy+px^{p-1}y\,dx=qx^{p-1}\,dx+rx^p\,dx
$$
..?

Comment: And for me is not obvious how for $ p=0 $
$$
\frac{q}{p}\,\Rightarrow\,q\log x\;?
$$
Same with $ p=-1 $
$$
\frac{r}{p+1}x\,\Rightarrow\,rx\log x\;?
$$
Can you explain a bit more..

Comment: Many thanks @Yves Daoust for your help

Comment: Someone could give me some hints..;) ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{ax}{( b + cy + ex)} y' = k$$ Fist, let
$$b+c y+e x=z \implies y=\frac{z-b-e x}{c}\implies \frac{a x \left(z'-e\right)}{c z}=k$$ which is not bad at all.
$$a x z'- k c z=a ex$$
$$a x z'- k c z=0\implies z=C x^{\frac{c k}{a}}$$ Now, variation of the parameter leads to 
$$C'=e x^{-\frac{c k}{a}}\implies C=\frac{e x^{1-\frac{c k}{a}}}{1-\frac{c k}{a}}+K\implies z=\frac{e x}{1-\frac{c k}{a}}+K x^{\frac{c k}{a}}$$

Comment: Thanks @Claude Leibovici. I'll look more in detail to get your development.