# Need hints on how to integrate this solved equation?

Tags: calculus

The differential is solved (thanks @Yves Daoust) but I don't get how he did the integration.
$$
y'x^p+px^{p-1}y=qx^{p-1}+rx^p
$$
to
$$
yx^p=\frac qp x^p+\frac r{p+1}x^{p+1}+c
$$
Can you show me the intermediate steps on how to integrate this ?
$$
x^p\,dy+px^{p-1}y\,dx=qx^{p-1}\,dx+rx^p\,dx
$$
And then more: 
for particular solution: with $ p = 0$ how one gets this?
$$
\frac{q}{p}\,\Rightarrow\,q\log x\;?
$$
or with $ p = -1 $, I do not get either?
$$
\frac{r}{p+1}x\,\Rightarrow\,rx\log x\;?
$$

(my original question: [Help me to solve a basic (?) differential equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575941/) )

Comment: $(y x^p)' = y' x^p + p y x^{p-1}$ then $y x^p = \int (q x^{p-1}+r x^p) dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from

$$y'x^p+px^{p-1}y=qx^{p-1}+rx^p\tag{1}$$

divide every term by $x^p$ to form

$$y'+\frac{p}{x}y=\frac{q}{x}+r$$

which is a [linear first order differential equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx). The integrating factor is

$$u(x)=\text{exp}\left(\int\frac{p}{x}\,dx\right)=x^p$$

therefore
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{p}y\right)=qx^{p-1}+rx^p$$
$$x^{p}y=\int (qx^{p-1}+rx^p)\,dx$$
$$x^{p}y=x^p\left(\frac{q}{p}+\frac{rx}{p+1}\right)+c_1$$
which gives
$$y=\frac{q}{p}+\frac{rx}{p+1}+c_1x^{-p}\tag{2}$$
By $(2)$, we see that $p\neq 0$ and $p\neq 1$. To find out what happens at these two values, we evaluate $(1)$ when $p=0$ and $p=-1$. At $p=0$, $(1)$ becomes

$$y'=\frac{q}{x}+r$$
$$dy =\left(\frac{q}{x}+r\right)dx$$
integrate both sides
$$y=q\ln|x|+rx+c_2\tag{3}$$
Similarly, for $p=-1$, $(1)$ becomes

$$\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}y=\frac{q}{x^2}+\frac{r}{x}$$
$$y'-\frac{1}{x}y=\frac{q+rx}{x}$$

which is a linear first order differential equation. The integrating factor is

$$u(x)=\text{exp}\left(-\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx\right)=x^{-1}$$
hence
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{-1}y\right)=\frac{q+rx}{x^2}$$
$$x^{-1}y=\int \left(\frac{q+rx}{x^2}\right)\,dx$$
$$x^{-1}y=r\ln|x|-\frac{q}{x}+c_3$$
which gives
$$y=rx\ln|x|-q+c_3x\tag{4}$$

Comment: Many thanks @Axion004 for your support.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'x^p+px^{p-1}y=qx^{p-1}+rx^p$$

Note that $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ and here we have $f=x^p \implies f'=px^{p=1}$ and $g=y \implies g'=y'$. So that $(yx^p)'=y'x^p+px^{p-1}y$. You can write:
$$(yx^p)'=qx^{p-1}+rx^p$$
And integrate both sides:
$$yx^p= \int qx^{p-1}+rx^p dx $$
$$yx^p= \frac  {qx^p}p+\dfrac {rx^{p+1}}{p+1}+C $$

Comment: Thanks for your input @Aryadeva

Comment: You're welcome Chris @Chris_toph